# How to use a semaphore and struct for multi threads

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, semaphore

I am trying to have a multithread program that work with struct and semaphore.
I am not sure how to pass those values. Therefore I decided to pass my struct by reference and put my semaphore as a global variable.
What I am trying to do is to make two threads count to 20
(where one would be t1 = 0, 2 , 4 ,6 ... 20 and t2 = 1, 3 , ... , 19)
Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define SEM_sem;
#define MaxVal 20;

typedef struct {
    int startVal;
    int maxVal;
 } countStruct;

sem_t *sem;

void *t1(void *param) {

countStruct *counting;
counting = (countStruct *) param;
int i = counting->startVal;
while(i <= counting->maxVal) {
    printf("%d\n",i);
    i = i + 2;
    sem_post(sem);
    sem_wait(sem);
}
pthread_exit(0);
}

void *t2(void *param) {

countStruct *counting;
counting = (countStruct *) param;
int i = counting->startVal;
while(i <= counting->maxVal) {
    printf("%d\n",i);
    i = i + 2;
    sem_post(sem);
    sem_wait(sem);
}
pthread_exit(0);
```

}

```
int main() {
sem = sem_open(SEM_sem, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666, 0);

if (sem == SEM_FAILED) {
    printf("sem_open() failed\n");
    sem_unlink(SEM_mpoulinl);
    return(8);
}

pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_t tid1, tid2

countStruct array_struct[3];
int i = 0;
for(i ; i < 2 ; i++) {
    array_struct[i].startVal = i;
    array_struct[i].maxVal = MaxVal;
}

pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, t1, (void*)&array_struct[0]);
sleep(1);
pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, t=2, (void*)&array_struct[1]);

pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
pthread_join(tid2, NULL);

sem_close(sem);
sem_unlink(SEM_mpoulinl);
return(0);
}
```

Unfortunately my code print t1 then t2.
Why is it not working?
is it because my semaphore is global?
I tested taking out sem_post(sem) sem_wait(sem) and the code still work, therefore those two things does not seem to work or am I not using it appropriately?

Thank you!

Comment: You need two semaphores so that t1 can tell t2 to proceed and vice versa. As it is there is nothing stopping one thread from immediately grabbing the semaphore as soon as it is released (which is exactly what you are observing).

Comment: You don't even need semaphores if each thread only manipulates a certain array index and doesn't touch anything else. Then you can use the same callback for each thread too and they will be re-entrant.